# Retrieve automatically-set values from DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model where certain fields are automatically set (timestamp, pk).

```
# models.py
class thisModel(models.Model):
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        topic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        message = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
```

Below is my serializer:

```
# serializer.py
class thisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = thisModel
        fields = ('pk', 'topic', 'timestamp', 'message',)
```

When creating my model, I need only specify the topic and message.

```
data={}
data['topic'] = 'paper'
data['message'] = 'This is a message'
serializer = thisSerializer(data=data)
if serializer.is_valid(): # True
    serializer.save()
    # I would like to retrieve the PK and Timestamp here
```

The model is created, but I have no way of retrieving that model as I have no unique identifier for it.

Doing `serializer.data['topic']` and `serializer.data['message']` returns these fields as intended.

Doing `serializer.data['pk']` returns an error: `KeyError: 'pk'`

Any idea on how to retrieve these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` attribute on `serializer` is just the data which you specified, but `serializer.save()` returns the newly created object.  Try this:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    obj = serializer.save()
    new_pk = obj.pk
    new_timestamp = obj.timestamp
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try this. Thank you!